# refinerycms undefined method `escape_path' for Rack::Utils:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm upgrading an old project which is on heroku cedar-10 to cedar-14 and in preparation to get it working I've had to upgrade a number of things.

When upgrading refinerycms from 1.0.8 to 1.0.11 I get this error when going to the refinery/images area;

```
undefined method `escape_path' for Rack::Utils:Module

Extracted source (around line #4): 

Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-images-1.0.11/app/views/admin/images/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (360.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 454ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `escape_path' for Rack::Utils:Module):
    1: <ul id="image_grid" class="<%= ['clearfix', 'pagination_frame', pagination_css_class].compact.join(' ') %>">
    2:   <% @images.each_with_index do |image, index| -%>
    3:     <li id="image_<%= image.id %>" class='image_<%= index % 5 %>'>
    4:       <%= image_fu image, '135x135#c', :title => image.title %>
    5:       <span class='actions'>
    6:         <%= link_to refinery_icon_tag('eye.png'), image.url,
    7:                     :target => "_blank",


Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.2ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (11.6ms)
```

**update**

I tried updating rack but rails 3.0.20 relies on rack 1.2.5, rack 1.2.5 does not include the escape_path method!

Now I'm wondering if it's easy to monkey patch rack or upgrade to rails 3.1
Updating to rails 3.1 though seems to require updating refinerycms and all it's friends. Not as fun as it sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand old `Rack::Utils` module with missing method.

```
require 'rack/utils'

module Rack
  module Utils
    def escape_path(s)
      escape(s).gsub('+', '%20')
    end
    module_function :escape_path
  end
end
```

Add it to `config/initializers` to file named `expand_rack.rb` for example